# How to resolve null reference exception thrown by HttpContext.Session (in Controller method) in unit test project C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a mvc project and I want to write unit test methods to test the controller methods. I don't want to simply test if the controller is returning correct view or not, I want to test the model object returned by the partialViewResult. 
Below is the controller method. This returns a model object to a view to populate the grid. I want to test if it returns 10 records in the model object inside partialview.

```
 public ActionResult productGrid (string pID = null)
{
   List<product> listproductModel = new List<product>();
   List<productModel> listviewproductModel = new List<productModel>();
   try {
   listproductModel = GetProductDetails(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pId) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(pId));
   if (listproductModel != null)
            {
                Mapper.Map(listproductModel, listViewproductModel); // Using Auto mapper to map 
            }
     HttpContext.Session["ProductList"] = listViewproductModel;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.WriteLog(LogType.ERROR, ex.Message, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        return PartialView("_productGrid", listViewproductModel);
    }
```

Below is the unit test method (I am a newbie in this so it may have a lot of mistakes). I changed my testmethod a bit. it is able to check the number of records in the model object returned by the controller method to the view but another error is occurring. Please check the following code for details.

```
  public void productGridTest()
    {
        string platformId = null;
        var obj = new ProductController();
        var result = obj.productGrid(platformId) as PartialViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual(true, ((IList<productModel>)result.ViewData.Model).Count == 10, "Error");
    }
```

Where, productModel is a model object containing details of the products.

The above testmethod works properly when I put

```
  HttpContext.Session["ProductList"] = listViewproductModel;
```

in the controller method inside COMMENTS (in other words, disable the statement). Otherwise, it returns null reference exception due to this statement. Please help me out how to resolve this error! 
 Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you confirm by line 3 you mean `PartialViewResult result =...`? Also, is this the actual code as you declare `platformId` but pass `pId`? Hard to help if we are not looking at the actual code!

Comment: I am extremely sorry. Yes platformID should be pId. My bad :(

Comment: Thank you. And please confirm the exact line that errors please?

Comment: PartialViewResult result = target.productGrid(pId) as PartialViewResult; - this is where the following error occurs: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Controller name is only "Controller"? You need the controller that you want to test, not a generic. As example, if I have a UserController to test:

```
var controller = new UserController()
var result = controller.productGrid("");

Assert.IsNotNull(result);

var viewResult = result as PartialViewResult;
var hasErrors = controller.ModelState.Values.Any(d => d.Errors.Any());

Assert.IsFalse(hasErrors);
Assert.IsInstanceOf<PartialViewResult>(result);
Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
Assert.AreEqual(true, result.ViewData.Count > 0);
```

Comment: Assert.IsInstanceOf<PartialViewResult>(result); is not supported in my IDE. I am using VS 2010 Professional.

Comment: IsInstanceOf Is an Assert of NUnit test framework. You can install it in yout project or simply ignore this assert. If you don't know the NUnit, check the frameworks website: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=home